# How to save clicked image in a custom folder of the app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want the image clicked by the camera to be saved in my custom folder "MyCameraApp" and that image to be displayed in the app's listview.

Below is the TakePhoto() code:

```
/**
 * take a photo
 */
private void activeTakePhoto() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        String fileName = "temp.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver()
                .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        values);
        takePictureIntent
                .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

The TakePhoto() function calls REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:

```
case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE &&
                    resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor =
                        managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null,
                                null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                MyImage image = new MyImage();
                image.setTitle("Test");
                image.setDescription(
                        "test take a photo and add it to list view");
                image.setDatetime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                image.setPath(picturePath);
                images.add(image);
                daOdb.addImage(image);
                imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.invalidateViews();
            }
    }
```

Comment: mhhh. Maybe adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is the key. list.invalidateViews() for me, looks like it has no influence on the content in the adapter itself, it refreshs the views only. Just give it a try.

Comment: This is more of a find the error in my code than a question

Comment: Ya,kind of... so plz help!! I need it..

Comment: What is exactly your problem? i cant see any error log or any question in your post.

Comment: Theres no error in the code. I just want it to work in a different way.

Comment: As in, the image which i click from the camera, it gets displayed in the app's listview but gets saved in the default camera folder of the phone.I want that image to be saved in my own folder "MyCameraApp" and then get displayed in the app too.

Comment: So my question is what should i add in my code to do the above??